# How to direct stream(kafka) a JSON file in spark and convert it into RDD?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql

Wrote a code that direct streams(kafka) word count when file is given(in producer)

code :

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext

from operator import add
import sys
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils
## Constants
APP_NAME = "PythonStreamingDirectKafkaWordCount"
##OTHER FUNCTIONS/CLASSES

def main():
    sc = SparkContext(appName="PythonStreamingDirectKafkaWordCount")
    ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 2)

    brokers, topic = sys.argv[1:]
    kvs = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, [topic], {"metadata.broker.list": brokers})
    lines = kvs.map(lambda x: x[1])
    counts = lines.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" ")) \
        .map(lambda word: (word, 1)) \
        .reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a+b)
    counts.pprint()

    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
if __name__ == "__main__":

   main()
```

Need to convert the input json file to spark Dataframe using Dstream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

Once you have your variable containing the TransformedDStream `kvs`, you can just create a map of DStreams and pass the data to a handler function like this:

```
data = kvs.map( lambda tuple: tuple[1] )
data.foreachRDD( lambda yourRdd: readMyRddsFromKafkaStream( yourRdd ) )
```

You should define the handler function that should create the dataframe using your JSON data:

```
def readMyRddsFromKafkaStream( readRdd ):
  # Put RDD into a Dataframe
  df = spark.read.json( readRdd )
  df.registerTempTable( "temporary_table" )
  df = spark.sql( """
    SELECT
      *
    FROM
      temporary_table
  """ )
  df.show()
```

Hope it helps my friends :)